# MS Access Stored Procedure and Sql from VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I have built a system in VB.NET where all the sql is automatically generated and executed with CommandType.Text (default). In addition I have created a stored procedure in my access database I wish to use like a "view".

I wish to execute an sql query which utilizes the stored procedure. Is this kind of action possible?

I'm guessing it isn't since the CommandType can only be Text, Table, or StoredProcedure.

```
    Public Function GetTable(ByVal query As String) As DataSet
        Dim connectionString As String = String.Empty
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + GlobalSettings.Databases(GlobalSettings.DatabaseTypes.Submission) + ";"
        Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
        Dim dataAdpter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet

        Try
            connection.Open()
            dataAdpter.Fill(dataSet)

        Catch loException As OleDbException
            Throw loException
        Finally
            If connection IsNot Nothing Then connection.Close()
        End Try

        Return dataSet
    End Function
```

I also don't want all my sql to be stored procedures. I prefer to execute as CommandType.Text.

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details about the so called stored procedure? and how do you want to call it? IE `SELECT * from yourQuery WHERE...` or just `yourQuery`)

Comment: Hey Steve. The stored procedure is just a select statement joining together a few tables allowing a simple way to get data.

I will just join to it in the query.

SELECT A.A, A.B, SP.A, SP.B
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN STORED_PROCEDURE SP ON SP.X = A.X

Comment: Then you could call it with the syntax above: SELECT * FROM spname/queryname and use CommandText for CommandType. In alternative you could call it with just spname/queryname in the CommandText and use StoredProcedure in CommandType